# How to add a dialog box in mapview in android

Tags: android, dialog, android-mapview

just like Google gives a small info dialog box right above the marker in maps, i am trying to do something similar. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked several times on stackoverflow.
Mainly the answers are pointing towards [android-mapviewballoons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons).

You'll have to implement a popup on your own. Google didn't deliver this ability via a simple API-call in the GoogleMaps API yet.